# I need to delete QDBUSMessage ? (in QT)

Tags: c++, qt, heap-memory

i use `QDBusMessage msg = QDBusMessage::createMethodCall(...)`

But, I don't know well about `QDBusMessage`.

the msg is on the heap? or stack?

if this is heap area, I need to delete.

but, if this is stack area, I don't need to delete.

where is this area?

So, do I need to delete method `createMethodCall`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point is that the function `QDBusMessage::createMethodCall` returns a `QDBusMessage` **value** and not a pointer. So you couldn't call `delete` on it even if you wanted to.

If the API returned a `QDBusMessage *`, then you would want to find out if it needs to be `delete`d. But as it stands, it's a safe "no".

---

Some general notes:

- Prefer `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared` when creating heap objects.
- If you `new` an object, then you should at some point `delete` it.
- If you `new[]` an object, then you should at some point `delete[]` it.
- If a factory function returns a pointer, then its documentation should tell you if you are responsible for freeing the memory.
- If a factory function (such as this one) returns a value, then it is **clearly** not your responsibility to worry about its memory management.